# How to solve this JavaScript scope issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a file content using jQuery `.get()` method like below

```
var news;
$.get('news.txt', function (dat) {
   news = dat;
   if ($('#removeN').is(':checked')) {
       news = "";
   }
   alert(news) // Displaying exact result;               
});
alert(news) // Displaying undefined..; Why?
```

Someone please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: make a synchronous call instead ?

Comment: There are so many dublicates out here... Can someone find one proper?

Comment: A dublicate is when Skrillex steals someone's material.

Answer (score 4):

**A**JAX is **asynchronous**.

Your last line runs before you get a response from the server.

Answer (score 3):

```
var news;
$.get('news.txt', function (dat) {
   news = dat;
   if ($('#removeN').is(':checked')) {
       news = "";
   }
   alert(news) // BEFORE THIS!         
});
alert(news) // THIS EXECUTES
```

use this instead if you want to do something with the news:

```
$.get('news.txt', function (dat) {
   news = dat;
   if ($('#removeN').is(':checked')) {
       news = "";
   }
   doSomething(news) // Displaying exact result;               
});

var doSomething = function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also be able to separate out concerns..

```
var news;
$.get('news.txt', function (dat) {
   //process news       
}).done(function(dat){
   //display news, or maybe more processing related to this particular function block
   alert(news);
}).fail(function(){
   //oops, something happened in attempting to get the news.
   alert("failed to get the news");
}).always(function(){
   //this eventually gets called regardless of outcome
});
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to $.get is a **callback**. Essentially what $.get is doing is setting up an event handler to the content loaded event, and saying "here's the function I want to run when this event is fired." Like others have said, it hasn't fired that event yet, so the code rambles through and finds your uninitialized variable.